# BibTeX Citation Style

Tags: bibtex

My goal is to have citations of the style

> [Newspaper Name] or [Newspaper Name, year]

Either is fine, and the difference between having square brackets vs parenthesis is negligible. Currently I am using

```
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
```

but my key problem is that if the name of the newspaper is longer than one word, i.e. Bangkok Post, the citation will only use the last word as if a last name; in this example the citation would be

> [Post, 2013]

where I am at least looking for

> [Bangkok Post, 2013] or [Bangkok Post]

If it makes any difference, I am using the command `\cite{}` for these citations. Thank you in advance for suggestions.

Here is the BibTeX entry for the above example from the database I am using for the articles

```
@article(14848CBDC1D8B7A0,
title={Partner of NSA leaks journalist held for 9 hours},
year={August 19, 2013},
journal={Bangkok Post (Thailand)},
ISSN={0125-0337},
)
```

Additionally I am using the article document class

Comment: I like how, at the time of this post, the editor has 106k reputation and the asker has 106 reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed your given bib entry a little bit to get the wanted result.  You will find two possibilities to do it: add an `author` field or an `key` field in your `bib` file.

Please try the following MWE, comiling with MiKTeX 2.9 without errors:

```
%File mb-bibtex.tex, then \jobname = mb-bibtex
\RequirePackage{filecontents}        % loading package filecontents
% writing file \jobname.bib, for example mb-bibtex.bib.
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article(14848CBDC1D8B7A0,
  title   = {Partner of {NSA} leaks journalist held for 9 hours},
  year    = {August 19, 2013},
  journal = {Bangkok Post (Thailand)},
  ISSN    = {0125-0337},
  key  = {Bangkok Post},
)
@article(Test,
  title   = {Partner of {NSA} leaks journalist held for 9 hours},
  year    = {August 19, 2013},
  journal = {Bangkok Post (Thailand)},
  ISSN    = {0125-0337},
  author  = {{Bangkok Post}},
)
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}    % better urls in bibliography

\begin{document}
Test of bibliography: 

\cite{14848CBDC1D8B7A0}, \cite{test}.
\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{\jobname}       % uses \jobname.bib, according to \jobname.tex
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: So if there is no author, I can use `key` in its place or for the full name of the "author" i just encapsulate it in a second set of braces?

Comment: @AlexMardikian They field `key`is a workaround (can result with a warning).  The second brackets are that the key is not changed (lower case or so). Better woukd be to add in your case an not existing author (no warning from BibTeX).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are okay with this:

```
\documentclass[12 pt]{article}

\begin{document}
Test. \cite {Bangkok Post}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
    \bibitem{Bangkok Post} Bangkok Post, 2020.
\end{thebibliography}
\end {document}
```